# How to refresh a page section using ajax/json?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i am building a chat website, now i working on **ONLINE USER**.
I use AJAX to refresh but i meet some problems with **Append.();**.
When refreshing section the same data appear again and again...That is the PHP file.

```
<?php
public function online(){
    $database = new DB();
    $db = $database->database();
    $array = array();
    $ref = $_SESSION['oc_users_ref'];

    $time_out = time()-5;
    $time = time();

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_users WHERE users_online = 0");

    $updateOnline = $db->query("UPDATE oc_users SET users_online = 1 WHERE users_lastcome < '$time_out'");

    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_users WHERE users_ref <> '$ref' AND users_online = 0 ORDER BY users_lastcome DESC");

     while($data = $q->fetch()) {
        if($data['users_online'] == 1){
            $class = "opacity30";
        }else{
            $class = '';
        }
        $array[] = $data;
     }
     print json_encode($array);
} ?>
```

**Now the Javascript**

```js
function getOnline(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "conf/users.php?act=online",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data) {
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
   for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
   {
    $('#printOnline').append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=javascript:chatWith("'+json[i].users_nickname+'")><i></i>'+json[i].users_nickname+'</a></li>');
   }
  }
 });
}
setInterval('getOnline()',10000);
```

**And the result***

User001
User001
User001
User001
User001
User001
User001
User001

Please help me...Great Thanks

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the user list before updating:

```
function getOnline(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "conf/users.php?act=online",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#printOnline').html("");
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
            {
                $('#printOnline').append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=javascript:chatWith("'+json[i].users_nickname+'")><i></i>'+json[i].users_nickname+'</a></li>');
            }
        }
    });
}
setInterval('getOnline()',10000);
```

Comment: Thanks you it work fine...Now show me the XSS vulnerability please

Comment: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/preventing-cross-site-scripting-and-sql-injection. You need to addslashes() your variables that go into your query